# Add external libraries in new library/jar-file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

Is it possible to export a JAR File with IntelliJ using Gradle, containing other libraries/jar? I am using Gradle dependencies to import the external code.

So if someone wants to use my final library or jar file the person does not have to import my lib files and the external lib files separately.

Comment: I don't have any experience with IntelliJ, but it's definitely possible to include other jar libraries within your own jar. Just include the libraries in a directory in the jar and make sure the Class-Path attribute in the manifest file points to them (e.g., `Class-Path: lib/example.jar`).

Comment: Generally, it's better practice to store your libraries in a subfolder somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you need is [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).